# Spring MVC: calls from JSP not going to the controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to pass parameters from JSP to the Spring MVC controller. However the controller doesn't get called. I have read many related posts regarding this and have tried various solutions provided but it's not working for me.

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<display-name>MyList</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mylist</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mylist</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/subcategory/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findSubcategory(@PathVariable int id,Model model) {
    List<Category> subCategoryList = this.myListDao.getSubCategories(id);
    model.addAttribute("subcategories", subCategoryList);
    return "searchCategory" ;
}
```

The relevant code from My JSP is as follows

```
<spring:url value="/subcategory/1" var="formUrl"/>
 <c:forEach var="category"  varStatus="status" items="${categories}">      
     <li><a href="${fn:escapeXml(formUrl)}">${category.description}</a></li>   
  </c:forEach>
```

It works when I have the url as `/subcategory.html` and have `@RequestMapping("/subcategory")` in my controller. When I use `/subcategory/1` and change the corresponding request mapping, it does not work. I have tried various url patterns such as `<url-pattern>/mylist/*</url-pattern><url-pattern>/MyList/*</url-pattern>`etc. but nothing is working. I would really appreciate any help in solving this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current servlet mapping is overriding the default or root servlet mapping,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mylist</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your following mapping allows any request with *.html to be accepted hence your invocation to `/subcategory.html` worked without any issues.

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

Instead it should be changed to,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mylist</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Some points to remember,

1. `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

   This pattern is usually recommended with `Filter` to continue with filter chaining. Using this pattern otherwise will make you to take care of all responsibilities like serving static resources etc to be handled explicitly.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked. I was initially skeptical regarding using / for the url pattern but this is the only solution that seems to work.

Comment: This was working fine...but when I cleared the browser cached data..it is not showing the CSS...on the console I get an error 'code' No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MyList/resources/....in DispatcherServlet. I tried using <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>  and   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/vendors/**" location="/vendors/"/>'code'  but then it does not take me to the controller...It works fine with the *.html url mapping. Any clue why it happens?

Comment: @Love2LearnNShare this seems to be another issue related to your static resource configuration. I would suggest to raise another question for this. It is more to do with where you have placed your static resources. Also mention your directory structure for the same

Comment: Well this works fine if I use .html instead of / in the url mapping. Looks like the calls are now being handled by the dispatcher servlet when I use /..anyways thanks..I will post another question related to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/subcategory/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

instead of path, you should use value, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/subcategory/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call cannot reach the controller because your request mapping "/subcategory/{id}" does not match any url-patterns defined with your dispatcher servlet. You can try replacing these lines:

```
<url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

with

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```